Azure Web App publishing model container option not working with Terraform
I want to create a web app with a container as a publishing model using Terraform. The only option I found in Terraform docs was to use the azurerm_linux_web_app resource with block application_stack but I got the error that this is an unsupported block type. How can I tell Azure to provision a web app with a container not a code publishing model using Terraform? I have a docker image that is publically accessible and I will reference that in my app service. I really appreciate any help you can provide.
my terraform version is v1.9.2
my hashicorp/azurerm is ~> 3.0
Error:
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│ 
│   on main.tf line 122, in resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app":
│  122:   application_stack{
│ 
│ Blocks of type "application_stack" are not expected here.

main.tf
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app" {
  name                = "${var.app_service_name_prefix}${random_string.random.result}"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.asp.id

  application_stack{
    docker_image_name = var.docker_image_name
    docker_registry_url = var.docker_registry_url
  }

  app_settings = {
    "STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"  = azurerm_storage_account.storage.primary_connection_string
  }

}


Your provider version is probably something other than what you expect. You can execute terraform providers in the root module to confirm.


Error:Unsupported block type

Application_stack block is only supported in older versions of terraform azurerm provider. As a workaround to provision a web app with a container docker image, you can include linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|<dockerimage>" under site_config = {} block as shown below.
Refer SO by @Nancy Xiong for the relevant approach.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.112.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
 name = "Jahnavi"
 }
 resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "example"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app" {
  name                = "examplejahapps"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.example.id
  site_config{
    linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|<dockerimagepath>"
  }
}




I tried this, but linux_fx_version is not supported by latest version. and I cannot downgrade. My versions are mentioned in the post.

3.112.0 did the trick
